TestRail-report - Expected VS Actual
I have a question regarding TestRail reporting. As the team lead, I want to monitor the effort utilized by each tester in a project.
For example, suppose Kannan is assigned as a tester and has 10 test cases to execute, with an estimated execution time of 1 hour for all the test cases. In that case, I want to determine whether the tester has executed the test cases within the estimated time or exceeded it.
